# Infinity as a limit in an indeterminate form

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

There is this limit
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\ln x}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}$$
for which I built a graph and I know the answer, so the question is not about how to compute it, but about my observation that when $x$ approaches $1$ from the right, the $\ln x =  0^+ $, but when $x$ approaches $1$ from the left, the $\ln x =  0^-$.

Based on that fact, even though it's an an indeterminate form $0 : 0$, can I already say that the limit does not exist or is that not enough and I need to turn it into a determinate form? And if I have to turn it into a determinate form, how can I do that?

Comment: The answer is in the name _indeterminate form_:  you have not determined whether the limit exists or not.  As such, you have to use various techniques you have learned to rewrite the limit in a form that can tell you whether the limit exists or not.

Comment: "an indeterminate form $\infty:\infty$": please justify.

Comment: @YvesDaoust agree, I mistyped. I was thinking about the answer.

Comment: Basically $x=1$ is a simple zero of the numerator and a double zero of the denominator, so after "cancelling one $(x-1)$" the denominator still goes to zero but the numerator does not, and the limit does not exist. The concecpt of the order (or multiplicity) of a point as a zero (or a pole) is made more precise in a course on complex analysis. For polynomials it agrees with the usual multiplicity of a zero from school math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To evaluate indetermination just plug in the limit value for numerator and denominator to see that it is in the form $\frac 0 0$.

For the solution we can avoid l'Hospital by $x-1=t \to 0$ to obtain

$$\frac{\ln x}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}=\frac{\ln (1+t)}{t^{2}}=\frac1t\frac{\ln (1+t)}{t}$$

with $\frac{\ln (1+t)}{t}\to 1$ therefore we can conclude that limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

You don't "turn" an expression into an indeterminate form. It *is* an indeterminate form until you have computed its limit.

You did recognize an indeterminate form of the type $\dfrac00$, now your task is to evaluate it. L'Hospital is a way.

Comment: I understand now that I have to compute the limit, I don't know how. And I can't use L'Hospital because it is in the book before L'Hospital is explained so it's assumed that we don't use it.

Comment: @alekscooper: review your theory of limits.